# Is it required/recommended to run the Postgresql server process with the `postgres` OS user?

Tags: postgresql

If I were to run 2 or 3 `postgres` OS processes (one physical machine, multiple `postgres -D ...` processes), would it be more secure to run them under different OS users (ie other than the `postgres` user)?

Or is there a specific reason to run them all under the `postgres` user?

Comment: You mean 2 or 2 different servers, each one running PostgreSQL, or do you mean one server on which multiple separate PostgreSQL instances run? The user you choose to run PostgreSQL is arbitrary, it is just that all distributions, documentation and tools use *postgres* by default.